# TDA7294 blew up

Tags: amplifier, pcb-design, short-circuit

I have created this schematic connection of TDA7294 on and had a PCB solution.
Connected to power supply +-25VDC. But at first start the TDA7294 blew up without any load on output pin. I started check every connection, compared details with data sheet but cannot find any issue which could lead to destroying particular amplifier.
Is the any experienced person with this chip which can express his (her) view according the picture or give some advice. Maybe I forget something. I cannot understand the reason why is it blew up.
Thank you in advance.
[image: this]

Comment: Did you check the voltages on the power pins, usually exploding chips come from reversing polarity on power lines, or exceeding the voltage on the supply

Comment: Yes I checked. The polarity is correct. The voltage is +-25VDC. Not more.

Comment: Did you measure that voltage on the pins of the chip on the board? I usually measure the voltage on the pins, to make sure I didn't make a schematic or PCB error

Comment: Check if the positive and the negative rail are coming up at the same time (or one after another in the order specified in the datasheet). If they don't, some parasitic thyristor inside the chip may trigger and cause a short. This is a general advice with dual-rail power amplifiers.

Comment: After blew up I desoldered chip. I measured +25VDC between pin holes 7/13 - 1
And -25VDC between pinholes 15/8  -  1

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.